# VSCode launch.json Failed to start local API Gateway: Timeout while waiting for command: "sam local start-api"

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, visual-studio-code, local, sam

I have been banging my head on this for a few days and I am coming up empty. I have an API that I can run locally just fine via the command line-

sam local start-api

or

sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction

I USED to be able to run the same api via my launch.json configuration as well but suddenly for no reason I have been able to identify, I am now getting:

2021-05-19 12:18:32 [ERROR]: **Timeout while waiting for command: "sam local start-api"**
2021-05-19 12:18:32 [ERROR]: **Failed to start local API Gateway: Timeout while waiting for command: "sam local start-api"**
2021-05-19 12:18:32 [INFO]: Sending request to local API: http://127.0.0.1:5858/hello?

My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "name": "Simple API lambda-nodejs14.x:HelloWorldFunction (nodejs14.x)",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "api",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/lambda-nodejs14.x/template.yaml",
                "logicalId": "HelloWorldFunction"
            },
            "api": {
                "path": "/hello",
                "httpMethod": "get",
                "payload": {
                    "json": {}
                }
            },
            "lambda": {
                "runtime": "nodejs14.x"
            },
            "sam": {},
            "aws":{}
        }
```

I have reduced this to the simplest possible scenario by trying with the helloWorld test project.

My aws_toolkit log looks like this:

> 2021-05-19 12:27:07 [INFO]: Build complete. 2021-05-19 12:27:07
> [INFO]: Starting SAM application locally 2021-05-19 12:27:07 [INFO]:
> Running: (not started) [C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd
> local start-api --template
> C:\Users\USERTEST\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctklc1oS3\output\template.yaml
> --env-vars C:\Users\USERTEST\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctklc1oS3\env-vars.json
> --port 5858 --debug-port 5859] 2021-05-19 12:27:07 [INFO]: AWS.running.command 2021-05-19 12:27:07 [ERROR]: Timeout while waiting
> for command: "sam local start-api" 2021-05-19 12:27:07 [ERROR]: Failed
> to start local API Gateway: Timeout while waiting for command: "sam
> local start-api" 2021-05-19 12:27:07 [WARN]: [Error: Timeout while
> waiting for command: "sam local start-api"    at
> c:\Users\BogartLisa.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.25.0\dist\extension.js:2452:1782
> at async lv.invoke
> (c:\Users\BogartLisa.vscode\extensions\amazonwebservices.aws-toolkit-vscode-1.25.0\dist\extension.js:2452:1677)]
> 2021-05-19 12:27:07 [INFO]: Sending request to local API:
> http://127.0.0.1:5858/hello? 2021-05-19 12:27:07 [VERBOSE]: SAM:
> command exited (code: null): PID 14376: [C:\Program
> Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\sam.cmd local start-api --template
> C:\Users\USERTEST\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctklc1oS3\output\template.yaml
> --env-vars C:\Users\USERTEST\AppData\Local\Temp\aws-toolkit-vscode\vsctklc1oS3\env-vars.json
> --port 5858 --debug-port 5859] 2021-05-19 12:27:12 [INFO]: Successfully sent a telemetry batch of 1 2021-05-19 12:27:13 [ERROR]:
> Local API failed to respond (ECONNREFUSED) after 30 retries, path:
> /hello

My vs code:
Version: 1.56.2 (user setup)
Commit: 054a9295330880ed74ceaedda236253b4f39a335
Date: 2021-05-12T17:13:13.157Z
Electron: 12.0.4
Chrome: 89.0.4389.114
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 8.9.255.24-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17134

aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.27 Python/3.7.9 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off

Does Anyone have any ideas for me?? I am out of ideas

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this problem was to increase the configured max time to wait to attach to the sam cli:

Settings > Extensions > AWS Configuration > Samcli > Debug > Attach > Timeout:Millis

Maximum time (in milliseconds) to wait for SAM output while starting a Local Lambda session

Mine was set at the default of 30 seconds and unfortunately for me, it was taking in excess of 1.5 minutes to attach (but that's a whole 'nother problem).

Comment: which version of VSCode is this? V 1.65.2 doesnt have a `AWS Configuration` section, but there is an `AWS Toolkit` section. But even under that there is no Debug under the Samcli section